# Cassandra stuck on server start - Windows 10

Tags: cassandra

I've installed Cassandra as wrote in "Cassandra. The definitive guide - O'Reilly", chapter 2.
But when i'm trying to start the server from prompt using

```
cd <cassandra-directory>/bin
cassandra -f
```

this is the result:

[image]

The prompt doesn't go over. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you talk to the server from another terminal? As far as I can see, the server has started up and is waiting for input.

Comment: That O'Reilly book has not released its new (2nd) edition yet, containing updates for Cassandra 3.0 and up.  Which means that you are using the edition published in 2010.  Cassandra has had many, many improvements since then, so you should consider looking for a newer source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The prompt doesn't go over. How can I solve this?

`cassandra -f` starts Cassandra in the foreground.  So when you <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to get out back to your prompt, it kills Cassandra (which you don't want).

You have two options:

- Leave that window alone, and connect to your node from another command window or application.
- Start Cassandra using `cassandra -p cassandra.pid`.  This still gives you the server output in STDOUT, but starts Cassandra in the background so the process continues to run even after you enter another command.

Comment: I also didn't understand that i have to launch cassandra.bat first, then open in another terminal cqlsh.bat !